# custom cellcustom uitableveiwcell with IB

Tags: uitableview, uitextview

I try to create a custom uitableviewcell, I create my custom cell with IB, I put the class of my cell, connect IB then I use the cell in this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    [cell.username setText:@"Load more"];
    [cell.testo setText:@""];
}
else {

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    PFObject *obj = [self.arrayMessaggi objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
    PFUser *user = [obj objectForKey:@"daUtente"];



    float height = [self getStringHeight:[obj objectForKey:@"TestoMessaggio"]
                                 andFont:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13]];

    NSLog(@"Height: %f",height);

    [cell.username setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 20)];
    [cell.username setText:[user objectForKey:@"username"]];

    [cell.testo setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 25, 300, height)];
    [cell.testo setText:[obj objectForKey:@"TestoMessaggio"]];
}


return cell;
```

}

the problem is that the textview height is wrong, the value height is correct but the frame of textview is more little, and then if I scroll up/down the frame of textview change to the size of IB.

Comment: username and testo are texfield or textview ? and please try to keep the whole code means if conditon to till last keep it in cell ==nill condition and run the code

Comment: username is an'uilabel while testo is an'uitextview! I try putting all inside the condition but the table is not good!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps u

```
 NSString *someText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj objectForKey:@"TestoMessaggio"]];
 CGSize constraintSize;
 constraintSize.width = 300.0f;
constraintSize.height =100000; 
CGSize stringSize =[someText sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 17] constrainedToSize: constraintSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGRect rect ;
      if (stringSize.height>37) {
           rect = CGRectMake(10, 150, 210, 20+stringSize.height);
      }
    else
     {
       rect = CGRectMake(10, 150, 210, 50);
      }
    yourtextview.frame=rect;
```